# getResponseCode = 404 with this site only

Tags: android, xml-parsing, rss, httpurlconnection

my code works fine with any RSS feed like BBC and fakeapi and sciencemag and so on. .. but I have tried to use RSS feed of fifa.com and ResponseCode result always = 404

what I have to do for now, please ???
 this my code for connection

```
//String address ="http://www.sciencemag.org/rss/news_current.xml";//worked
//   String address = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml";// worked
```

String address = "http://www.fifa.com/rss/index.xml"; //404 Error code

```
public Document httpconnection() {
    try {

        url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.e("TAG", "connection.getResponseCode()" + a);
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputStream);

        return xmlDoc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It does connect, however its giving file not found exception. I belive its document related ("java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.fifa.com/rss/index.xml") I suggest reading: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: @Raykud
thanks, but I have been trying something else like volley, but it still not working like others